# Add content to an document in Couch DB

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, post, couchdb

I am using CouchDB as my database and i am abel to add new documents to it via my RESTful Webserver.

I am now trying to add additional info to my added documents, but I can not quite figure out how to post it in the right document. All i can do is add new documents or overwrite them via PUT.

This is how i POST a new document:

```
@POST
    @Path("/{_id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postBetroffenePerson(@PathParam("_id")String _id, Person person){
        Betroffene betroffene = new Betroffene(_id, person);
        String betroffenePerson = gson.toJson(betroffene);
        JsonObject betroffenePerson1 = gson.fromJson(betroffenePerson, JsonObject.class);
        db.postObject(betroffenePerson1);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

db is my database :

```
 public void postObject(JsonObject object) {
  dbBetroffeneClient.save(object);
 }
```

Now i want to add additional information to "Betroffene" besides the id and person.

I also have a GET-Method to get specific "Betroffene" via their id.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to modify a CouchDB document is to fetch it, modify it in memory, and then replace it (using PUT). That's by design; there's no API for modifying specific fields of a document.